# getFilename returns an empty string

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have a [`SourceLocation`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html) that I wish to extract its filename from. Apparently, I should be able to do that by using [`SourceManager`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html)'s [`getFilename`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a9b04dbe66cc7b9aa6a96d6d0f281aa34). However, the result seems to always be an empty string when I process some header files.

I follow the source code and found that the issue is that in the `getFilename` function, which reads:

```
/// Return the filename of the file containing a SourceLocation.
StringRef getFilename(SourceLocation SpellingLoc) const {
  if (const FileEntry *F = getFileEntryForID(getFileID(SpellingLoc)))
    return F->getName();
  return StringRef();
}
```

The result of `getFileID` is somehow invalid in a sense that `SLocEntry` constructed from it will have `isFile` returning `false`. This causes [`getFileEntryForID`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/SourceManager_8h_source.html#l01010) (which does construct `SLocEntry` under the hood) to return a null pointer.

I have a workaround, which is:

```
StringRef myGetFilename(SourceLocation SpellingLoc) const {
  std::pair<FileID, unsigned> locInfo = getDecomposedExpansionLoc(SpellingLoc);
  if (const FileEntry *F = srcManager.getFileEntryForID(locInfo.first))
    return F->getName();
  return StringRef();
}
```

That is, call `getDecomposedExpansionLoc` first to get a raw `FileID` and use it in `getFileEntryForID` instead.

Experimentally, this seems to work well, but this is my first day with clang, so I'm very unsure if it's actually correct. So I have two questions:

1. Is this a bug in clang?
2. Is my workaround actually correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, so the problem seems to be that `getFilename` expects a specific kind of `SourceLocation`, namely "SpellingLoc". So, change:

```
srcManager.getFilename(loc)
```

to

```
srcManager.getFilename(srcManager.getSpellingLoc(loc))
```

will fix the problem.